# Is there a difference between the code that handles the review icon on the top nav bar on Stack Overflow and other sites on the network?

Tags: discussion, migration, new-nav

I ran across a bug that prompted me to create this bug report. [Review queue false negatives on the new top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357666/review-queue-false-negatives-on-the-new-top-bar) which has since been placed on hold as off topic. The message states

> "This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."

I found this confusing as I was under the impression that the idea was to standardize the new top nav bar across the stack exchange family of sites and the question is clearly about the software that "powers the Stack Exchange network".

It's clear from the numerous down votes that the SO community doesn't think it belongs there and I'm OK with that if there isn't a shared codebase between the nav bars review icon handling. Upon the first complaint I flagged it and requested migration here, then I was informed that [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them) so I edited the post to reflect that. If anything my efforts seemed to make matters worse.